# Change left-padded rows to right-padded rows

Tags: r, matrix, padding

**Problem:** I have `n`, `m`-length vectors in a `n by m` matrix.
These vectors are left-padded with `NA` values.

Example:

```
x = matrix( 1:12, ncol=4 )
x[lower.tri(x)] = NA
print(x)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    4    7   10
# [2,]   NA    5    8   11
# [3,]   NA   NA    9   12
```

**Question:** What is an efficient way to make the rows right-padded? My actual matrix is 4,000 by 25,000.

What I want:

```
y = matrix( c( 1, 5, 9, 4, 8, 12,
               7, 11, NA, 10, NA, NA ), ncol=4 )
print(y)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    4    7   10
# [2,]    5    8   11   NA
# [3,]    9   12   NA   NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two one-line solutions:

```
t(apply(x, 1, FUN=function(ii) c(ii[!is.na(ii)],ii[is.na(ii)])))

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    4    7   10
[2,]    5    8   11   NA
[3,]    9   12   NA   NA

matrix(apply(x, 1, FUN=function(ii) c(ii[!is.na(ii)],ii[is.na(ii)])),
 byrow=T,ncol=4)
```

The idea here is just to look through each row and find the NA sand move them behind the values that are not NAs (i.e. `!is.na`).

The second version is actually slightly faster on my machine:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
t(apply(x, 1, FUN=function(ii) c(ii[!is.na(ii)],ii[is.na(ii)]))),
matrix(apply(x, 1, FUN=function(ii) c(ii[!is.na(ii)],ii[is.na(ii)])),
 byrow=T,ncol=4)
) 

Unit: microseconds

    min     lq  median     uq     max neval
 58.159 61.152 62.2215 66.711 174.475   100
 51.317 53.883 54.7380 57.731 127.863   100
```

Comment: Thanks! That's interesting to know that `t` is slower than manually setting the dimensions in `matrix`. It makes sense, but I never would have thought of it.